# Delayed transaction and price calculation in Google Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce with Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I have an online accommodation booking site, which uses Google Analytics with enabled Enhanced Ecommerce through Google Tag Manager.

The question is, how can I set up a delayed transaction?

What I mean:

When out visitors come to the site, they just send an offer request for the accommodation owners. At this time we know only the transaction id and the selected products, but not the price.

Later, the accommodations owners calculate the price, and send an offer back to the client. This step is always made by the accommodation owner or the site admin, but never by the original client. This is the time when the transaction actually should made for the original client.

How can I achieve that this transaction go to the original client but with the data calculated later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/) for this, it can't be done in GTM.

You can send transaction not later than 4 hours after visitor's request being initiated.
You'll have to save additional data about your visitors on your servers to build MP request later:

- IP address (&uip),
- user agent (&ua),
- client ID (&cid),
- time since the initial request (&qt).